# repository element

Tags: java, maven

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy (default-deploy) on project mysticpaste: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.mysticcoders</groupId>
 <artifactId>mysticpaste</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <!-- TODO project name  -->
 <name>quickstart</name>
 <description></description>

 <!-- TODO
  <organization>
  <name>company name</name>
  <url>company url</url>
  </organization>
 -->

 <licenses>
  <license>
   <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
   <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
   <distribution>repo</distribution>
  </license>
 </licenses>

 <dependencies>
  <!--  WICKET DEPENDENCIES -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
   <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
   <version>${wicket.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <!--  SPRING DEPENDENCIES -->

  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.5</version>
     </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.5</version>
       </dependency> 

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency> 
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
       <version>2.5.5</version>
  </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

      <!-- Hibernate framework -->
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.GA</version>
 </dependency>

  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
 </dependency>

 <!-- MySQL database driver -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.9</version>
 </dependency>


  <!-- OPTIONAL 
   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
   <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
   <version>${wicket.version}</version>
   </dependency>
  -->

  <!-- LOGGING DEPENDENCIES - LOG4J -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.14</version>
  </dependency>

  <!--  JUNIT DEPENDENCY FOR TESTING -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.2</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

  <!--  JETTY DEPENDENCIES FOR TESTING  -->

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
   <version>${jetty.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
   <version>${jetty.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
   <artifactId>jetty-management</artifactId>
   <version>${jetty.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
 <filters>
        <filter>src/main/filters/filters-${env}.properties</filter>
    </filters>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
   </resource>
   <resource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>**</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </resource>
  </resources>
  <testResources>
   <testResource>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <directory>src/test/java</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>**</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
     <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
   </testResource>
  </testResources>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>   
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <properties>
  <wicket.version>1.3.5</wicket.version>
  <jetty.version>6.1.4</jetty.version>
     <env>DEV</env>
 </properties>

 <profiles>
      <profile>
          <id>DEV</id>
          <properties>
              <env>DEV</env>
          </properties>
      </profile>

      <profile>
          <id>QA</id>
          <properties>
              <env>QA</env>
          </properties>
      </profile>

      <profile>
          <id>PROD</id>
          <properties>
              <env>PROD</env>
          </properties>
      </profile>
 </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: A half-decent text of about two-three sentences describing your question would come a long way in helping others understand what you want to do. Dumping code/XML and an exception/error is not helping.

Comment: maybe you meant `mvn jboss-as:deploy` instead of `mvn deploy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is deploy the webapp to application server.
And to do this you are using the `mvn ... deploy` command.

The problem is `mvn deploy` is meant for deploying the output of your project (artifact) to maven repository. For example to share your classes with other co-workers.

If I'm correct you need some kind of `mvn jetty:run` or `mvn tomcat:run` command to do what you want.

Comment: irrelevant question: how do you highlight code snipets inline?

Comment: Surround the text with the grave accent key (next to number 1 key).

Comment: well,normally, a developer just performs `mvn install` and `mvn jetty:run`. Usually, a guy from infrastructure team uses `mvn deploy` to release  `SNAPSHOT` or a final version. `deploy` copies artifacts to  your repository and from there it's available to users to download.

Answer (score 1):

Please run mvn help:effective-pom looks like you're missing <distribution> tag or <repositories> tags.

Edit: As Vitaly Polonetsky righty mentioned you should probably just build and start server. I think Jetty is embedded. So try

```
 mvn clean install run:jetty
```

Comment: If  you are just doing a test run and want to see app get built. Try      mvn clean install