# Maven: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement?

Tags: maven

I am trying to run the command, `mvn release:perform`, but I get this error:

> ```
> Failed to execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.5:deploy
> (default-deploy) on project git-demo:
> Deployment failed: repository element
> was not specified in the POM inside
> distributionManagement element or in
> -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url
> parameter
> ```

Here's my `pom.xml` file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sonatype.blog</groupId>
    <artifactId>git-demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>git-demo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:Christian-Achilli-KP/git-demo.git</connection>
        <url>scm:git:git@github.com:Christian-Achilli-KP/git-demo.git</url>
        <developerConnection>scm:git:git@github.com:Christian-Achilli-KP/git-demo.git</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <distributionManagement>
        <!-- use the following if you're not using a snapshot version. -->
        <repository>
            <id>localSnap</id>
            <name>RepositoryProxyRel</name>
            <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- use the following if you ARE using a snapshot version. -->
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>MylocalSnap</id>
            <name>RepositoryProxySnap</name>
            <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Actually I can see the

> repository

declaration inside the

> distributionManagent

tag.

Here's my `settings.xml`:

```
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>localSnap</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>****</password>
        </server>

        <server>
            <id>MylocalSnap</id>
            <username>deployment</username>
            <password>****</password>
        </server>

        <server>
            <id>myserver</id>
            <username>tomcat</username>
            <password>tomcat</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
            <id>nexus</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>MacRoman</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>MacRoman</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            </properties>

            <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
            <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <url>http://central</url>
                    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
                    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>

</settings>
```

Any advice why it complains?

Comment: Have you called mvn release:prepare before ? and of coure there are identical Id's which will not work anymore.

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, I did called mvn:release and changed the id's. I will update the question with the new POM

Comment: Have you added .gitignore to ignore the target folder? Can you push updates to github that i can take a look ?

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, target folder is ignored. Here's the git: git://github.com/Christian-Achilli-KP/git-demo.git tks!

Comment: I've setuped a new project based on your content in github and it works perfect https://github.com/khmarbaise/git-demo Updated the maven-release-plugin to 2.1 instead of using a such old version...

Comment: You should remove the property settings from your settings.xml file. It's better to put them into the POM...

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, you pointed me in the right direction, I learned a lot (These are my first days with maven). One more thing: what properties you mean in the settings.xml should be moved in the Pom? like this one <project.build.sourceEncoding>MacRoman</project.build.sourceEncoding>?

Comment: FYI: You can also get this error if you are a Maven noob and type `mvn deploy` without a place to deploy it to.  To just deploy it to your local repository, type `mvn install` instead.

Answer (score 42):

Review the `pom.xml` file inside of `target/checkout/`.  Chances are, the `pom.xml` in your trunk or master branch does not have the `distributionManagement` tag.

Comment: A `clean` then retry fixed this for me.

Answer (score 12):

I got the same message ("repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element"). I checked /target/checkout/pom.xml and as per another answer and it really lacked `<distributionManagement>`.

It turned out that the problem was that `<distributionManagement>` was missing in pom.xml in my **master branch** (using git).

After cleaning up (`mvn release:rollback`, `mvn clean`, `mvn release:clean`, `git tag -d v1.0.0`) I run `mvn release` again and it worked.

Comment: Why does Maven care about your master branch if you're not using it?

Answer (score 6):

You can also override the deployment repository on the command line:
`-Darguments=-DaltDeploymentRepository=myreposid::default::http://my/url/releases`

Answer (score 2):

The ID of the two repos are both `localSnap`; that's probably not what you want and it might confuse Maven.

If that's not it: There might be more `repository` elements in your POM. Search the output of `mvn help:effective-pom` for `repository` to make sure the number and place of them is what you expect.

Comment: thanks, I tried both of yours advices but I could't come up with a working solution. In the effective POM there is indeed another place with the <repositories> tag but it does not contain anything that clashes what's in the <distributionManagement> tag. There is a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539917/repository-element but I don't get the answer, how it fits the question!

Comment: Is this a multi module build? If so, check parent POMs and versions. Maybe you forgot to update the version number and one module is still using an old parent POM.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this was something as simple as a missing version for my artifact - "1.1-SNAPSHOT"