# Maven deploy is throwing error

Tags: java, maven, deployment

I have a very simple / basic Web app. 
When I run

> mvn deploy -e

I am seeing the following error in the console.

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
>   (default-deploy) on project TestWebApp: Deployment failed: repository
>   element was not specified in the POM inside  distributionManagement
>   element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter ->
>   [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
>   Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy
>   (default-deploy) on project TestWebApp: Deployment failed: reposi tory
>   element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement
>   element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>           at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)

Maven section is:

```
<profile>
        <id>TestWebApp-Repo</id>
            <repositories>
                <distributionManagement>
                    <repository>
                      <id>TestWebApp_Repository</id>
                      <name>TestWebApp Applications Repository Internal</name>
                      <url>C:/Users/~/.m2/repository</url>
                      <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                      </releases>
                      <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                      </snapshots>
                    </repository>
                </distributionManagement>
            </repositories>
</profile>
```

Comment: can you run the command with -X flag

Comment: also do a project> clean and then run the command with -X (for verbose logging)

Comment: check this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910037/maven-repository-element-was-not-specified-in-the-pom-inside-distributionmanage

Comment: DistributionManagement is not part of `repositories`  http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management

Comment: I am seeing the following error when I ran with -X flag:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project TestWebApp: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside
 distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]

Comment: i am not understanding what you are saying. In the page you are referencing, repository in embedded in distributionmanagement.

Comment: khmarbaise, 
I moved distribution management out of settings.xml and inserted into the pom file. Now I am seeing the following error. It looks like an access issue now. Can anybody help me figure this out.

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project TestWebApp: Failed to deploy artifact
s/metadata: Cannot access scp://C:/Users/user/.m2/repository with type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
        at

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by moving distributionManagement into the pom file and changing the url to use file. The link http://maven.apache.org/wagon/index.html is very helpful. My solution is below:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>TestWebApp_Repository</id>
      <name>TestWebApp Applications Repository Internal</name>
      <url>file://C:/Users/user/.m2/repository</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>
      <id>TestWebApp_Repository</id>
      <name>TestWebApp Applications Repository Internal</name>
      <url>file://C:/Users/user/.m2/repository</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
    </snapshotRepository>
  </distributionManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to activate the profile `TestWebApp-Repo`:

`mvn -e -PTestWebApp-Repo deploy`

Or insert this snippet at the end of `<profile>`:

```
    <activation>
          <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
```