# mvn deploy is failing

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I'm facing problem while deploying and here is the error message I get. I have check my project Target folder has not created yet.

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ LoanCalculator ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.010 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-09-21T16:10:39+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/283M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project LoanCalculator: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Process finished with exit code 1

I checked on internet and not able to find the solution for this issue. I think it's related to pom.xml. Here is the related parts of pom.xml:

```
        <properties>
            <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        </properties>


        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfxtras</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfxtras-agenda</artifactId>
            <version>8.0-r1</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>2016.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>

            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring AOP dependency -->
            <dependency>
                    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I am not able to find the correct dependency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5910037/maven-repository-element-was-not-specified-in-the-pom-inside-distributionmanage)

Comment: with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13314394/1746118 as the answer.

Comment: Actually I dont have target folder in my Project because it is not executed once.

Answer (score 1):

If the target folder is not created, can you try doing a "mvn clean install" first and see if the build runs fine and that a "target" folder is created with the desired artifact.

And once you have confirmed that works, add a `distributionManagement` tag in your pom.xml, for example below, replace the test and url below with your desired repo manager configs/values, and then do a "mvn deploy".

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
           <id>test</id>
           <url>Repo path</url>
    </repository>
 </distributionManagement>
```